# Is there a way to visualize with equal interval in scatterplot with skipping the first date of month colliding the interval

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have this code written for visualization

```
ax = self.figure4.add_subplot(111)
ax.clear()
ax.scatter(dmy_yo.values, pred_val, color='blue', marker='+', 
label='FuturePredicted')  
ax.set_title('Future Date vs ErrorID (Future Prediction)')
ax.set_xlabel('Future Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Future ErrorID')
self.canvas4.draw()
```

I have tried it using

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator()
```

but I am not able to use it properly.

```
    ax.clear()
    ax.scatter(dmy_yo.values, pred_val, color='blue', marker='+', 
    label='FuturePredicted')  
    ax.set_title('Future Date vs ErrorID (Future Prediction)')
    ax.set_xlabel('Future Date')
    ax.set_ylabel('Future ErrorID')
    self.canvas4.draw()
```

I expect the result should be like the intervals should be separated equally in the x-axis. But on the 1st of each month the interval breaks.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Please try to make your answer clear providing a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).